# What's are the variables can be used from content.field_name with multiple values

Tags: theming, 8

I have created a field using test list type and rendering using custom twig code as below:

```
 {% for key, item in content.field_scope if key|first != '#' %}
    <li class="item-list">{{ item }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

In "for" argument, I manage to get value of **key** and **item** from the field. What are the other value which can be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{ content.field_name }}` is a renderable array. You are meant to simply print out `{{ content.field_name }}`.

If you need to change what is actually in the output, then you should create a **field--field-name.html.twig** or another applicable twig template suggestion name that works for you. Within it, you would have:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <li class="item-list">{{ item.content }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

That way, any time you render either `{{ content }}` containing this field or `{{ content.field_name }}` it will use that template and render it consistently.

Here is a real world example. I am working on a project where one of the fields is a select list of about 20 options. These option values correlate to icons in the theme, and they can use this field to attach an icon to a title field for presentation purpose.

Here is my twig file for **field--field-icon.html.twig**:

```
{% for item in items %}
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="/themes/custom/mytheme/build/img/svg-sprite.svg#{{ item.content }}"></use></svg>
{% endfor %}
```

`item.content` is just my field value, you don't have to do anything special here. So if the editor selects 'Alert', which the select list value is 'alert', `item.content` will print `alert` and the proper icon will display from the svg spritesheet.

[Here is a similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225060/57) I answered which may provide further insight on theming fields.

Comment: You're explanation are absolutely correct. Thanks for the guidance.